# Why does R load a variable as a factor when running from the command line but as character from inside RStudio?

Tags: r

I'm loading a csv inside R.

```
df = read.csv(path_to_df, sep = ",", header = TRUE) 
samples = df$sample 
str(samples)
```

When I run this script, I get two different data structures depending on whether I do it from inside the RStudio or the command line.

```
#From inside RStudio
chr [1:200] "sample1" "sample2" "sample3" ...

#From the command line
Factor w/ 200 levels "sample1",..: 3 4 2 1 78 77 76 75 74 73 ...
```

This discrepancy creates some issues later in my script. For now I added some tape with `as.character` to force the script to always read `df$sample` as
`samples = as.character(df$sample)`

My questions is: Why? Why does R do this? Is there a standard way to make R default to character?

Comment: Either you are running a different (obsolete) version of R on your command line, or you have some weird `.Rprofile` configuration that changes the default `stringsAsFactors` value.

Comment: Do you have an older version of R installed that is being called from the command line? This was the default behaviour of R before version 4. You can change your `read.csv` call to include the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so that both are the same, but perhaps you should investigate which version of R you are running from both RStudio and the command line using `R.Version()`

Answer (score 1):

Your command line R version might be before 4.0.0.

> "Hence, in the R Core meetings in Toulouse in 2019, it was decided to move towards using stringsAsFactors = FALSE by default, ideally starting with the 4.0.0 release."
> [Kurt Hornik, 2020](https://blog.r-project.org/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, just add explicitly the `stringsAsFactors` argument

```
df = read.csv(path_to_df, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```